# Accidentally deleted healthy UEFI partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have 1 ssd and 1 hdd in my laptop And I used ssd for booting both OS. I reinstalled windows on hdd so in that process windows had conflicts with existing UEFI partition so I deleted and then I realised I messed up for Ubuntu
Now my ssd has all Ubuntu files but. Can't boot into it without that healthy 100mb UEFI partition. It doesn't even Show on the f12 bios menu pleas help

My whole developer code base Is on Ubuntu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try boot-repair but if you deleted UEFI partition I don't think it will work.

Comment: If you first recreate the ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 with boot/esp flags (using gparted) or code ef00 if using gdisk. Then Boot-Repair's advanced mode and full reinstall of grub or just manually reinstalling grub in UEFI boot mode should work.